# TPL Dataflow pipeline unexpected ending

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

i'm new to TPL Dataflow, this is my first pipeline.

I'm pushing 1M rows to `EmpresasBuffer`. In batches of 1000, `EmpresasBuffer` send data to `SaveBlock`, that saves it to database. After saving, `ExitBlock` shows how many rows was processed until now.

This works with less rows. If I try pushing 10,000 rows, it works as expected, but with 1M rows, it fails silently.

Inspecting code I see that `SaveBlock` and `ExitBlock` are setted as **Completed**, but, this occurs before `EmpresasBuffer.Complete()` has been called.

This is the code that creates the pipeline:

```
var EmpresasBuffer = new BatchBlock<EmpresaModel>(1000, 
                        new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions { 
                               EnsureOrdered = false, 
                               BoundedCapacity = 10000 });
var SaveBlock = new TransformBlock<EmpresaModel[], int>(
                        async x => await SalvarEmpresaAsync(x), 
                        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { 
                               EnsureOrdered = false, 
                               MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 32, 
                               BoundedCapacity = 10000 });
car ExitBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(x => {
    Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}] Registros Importados: {TotalRows += x}");
});

EmpresasBuffer.LinkTo(SaveBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
SaveBlock.LinkTo(ExitBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
```

And this is the code I use to push data to `EmpresasBuffer`:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string linha;
    while ((linha = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //{...creates empresa class...}
        await EmpresasBuffer.SendAsync(empresa);
    }
}

//{...after the end of loop...}

EmpresasBuffer.Complete();

await ExitBlock.Completion;

Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}] Process finished!");
```

Whats wrong with my code?

This is the code of `SalvarEmpresaAsync`:

```
public static async Task<int> SalvarEmpresaAsync(EmpresaModel[] modelArray)
{
    using (var Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        Connection.Open();

        var TaskEmpresa = BulkInsert<EmpresaModel>(Connection, "Empresas", modelArray, PropertiesEmpresa);
        var TaskQuadroSocietario = BulkInsert<QuadroSocietarioModel>(Connection, "QuadroSocietario", modelArray.SelectMany(x => x.QuadrosSocietarios).AsEnumerable(), PropertiesQuadroSocietario);

        await TaskEmpresa;
        await TaskQuadroSocietario;
    }


    return modelArray.Length;
}


public static async Task BulkInsert<T>(SqlConnection connection, string tableName, IEnumerable<T> data, string[] columns) where T: class
{
     using (var BulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
     using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data, columns))
     {
         foreach (string property in columns)
         {
             BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(property, property));
         }

         BulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
         await BulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(reader);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do you see something not working?

Comment: What does `SalvarEmpresaAsync` do? If *it* fails, or hides errors with a `catch{}`, you won't notice any errors. There's no call to `Complete()` or `await ExitBlock.Completionl` either. Any errors thrown by `SalvarEmpresaAsync` will get rethrown in the final `await`

Comment: `BoundedCapacity = 10000` ? What happens on the 10001st?

Comment: In this code, the only things that can throw are in the missing code. Perhaps `SalvarEmpresaAsync` has an error?

Comment: Perhaps the program never awaits for completion? Perhaps the application runs out of memory because `SaveBlock` caches *10000* buffers of 1000 items each, keeping 10M rows in memory ?? And tries to perform *32* concurrent batch inserts in the *same* database? This guarantees blocking in the database. Assuming you use SqlBulkCopy, *remove* the MaxDop parameter completely and use a sensible `BoundedCapacity` number, although just `1` could be fine - there's little to be gained by buffering if SqlBulkCopy is consistently slow

Comment: Hi, I completed the code with the call to ´complete´. Sorry for the strange numbers, I was testing with very high and very low numbers trying to identify the error.

Comment: After the status change to complete in the Save and Exit blocks, my code keep running, reading the text file to add itens to the EmpresaBlock, but EmpresaBlock is full and refuse to add more itens, and SaveBlock stop getting itens from EmpresaBlock because it's status suddenly changed to complete.

Comment: The large numbers *are* the error most likely - causing blocking in the database because too many connections are trying to perform BULK INSERT operations. And there's still no code for `SalvarEmpresaAsync`, the only thing that could throw

Comment: The problem occurs even with low numbers. The difference is that with low numbers it take more time to occur, but it occur in the same way.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you were right. The error were in `SalvarEmpresaAsync`. Sometimes I got timeout in the execution, and I was not understanding why the error wasnt throwing. A simple try/catch in `SalvarEmpresaAsync` solved the problem.